# How do you disable the set width of parent element for child element?

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I have a div whose CSS sets all images to a certain width. I want to add another, child div wihthin this one but have its images unconstrained - to be whatever size they actually are.

I am unsure how to 'reset' the width property of these child elements, so it doesnt inherit the parents?

Would anyone know how this is done?

```
<div id='parent'>
  <img src='image.jpg'>

  <div id='child'>
    <img src='image.jpg'>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
   #parent img {
     width: 200px;
    }

    #child img {
     width: do not inherit #parent img css???
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto` does what I what:

```
#child img {
     width: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your own width.

```
#parent img {
     width: 200px;
    }

    #child img {
     width: 100px;
    }
```